# python built-in function fail to work

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, built-in

I am using Jupyter Notebook, and I noticed that my python built-in function all() doesn't work:

```
myL = [True, True, False, True]
all(myL)
```

This codes above return `True`, which is wrong. Why would a built-in function fail to work properly? What are the potential causes? Thanks!

Comment: That code should produce True.  Start the session over again, and then paste the entire session.

Comment: User error is one potential cause. It is probably the most likely explanation.

Comment: It returns `False` for me on both py2.7 and py3.5

Comment: Ok. a whole new session works. But why exactly some codes give the wrong results sometimes in an old session? Wouldn't it be kind of dangerous?

Comment: @Edamame: is there any possibility that you accidentally assigned a truthy value to `False`? , e.g. `False=True` or `False='False'` etc.

Comment: Or did you redefine the `all` function?